# Money data into ranges for a bar graph

Tags: excel

This is probably a simple one, but I am stuck.  I have a list of names associated with a money value and I need to put these money values into a bar graph.  The values range from 100 dollars to 500,000 and more.  So I need each bar to show a range ie <1K, 1K-2K, 2K-5K and so on.  I also need the data label to show how many names fall into that bar.  The names are irrelevant to the data but the values are all unique.

Comment: This might help https://superuser.com/a/679340/898351

Answer (score 0):

To get the Category for each dollar amount, I'd start by making a key for the categories, with the lower limit in one column and the name of the amount range in another.

```
   Limit    Category
      0      <=1k
    1,001    1k-2k
    2,001    2k-5k
```

Then go to your list and add a column for Category. If the name is in A2 and the amount is in B2, use =VLOOKUP(B2, *lookup_range*, 2, TRUE), to pull in the category name. Lookup range is the (absolute) range of the table created above. Make sure the last argument is set to True so you get an approximate match instead of #N/A.

Now you can sort by Category and use subtotals to arrive at a list with 3 columns: Category, Count, and Total Amount. I would use a combo chart to plot the amount on the primary axis and count on the secondary axis.